# On quadratic forms, Pontryagin Squares, and H^4(K(pi,2),U(1))

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

I am trying to get a concrete handle on the isomorphism $H^4(K(\pi_2,2),U(1)) \simeq \{$quadratic forms $\pi_2 \to U(1) \}$. This is explained in Eilenberg and Maclane's http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969702 and its companion but I am having a hard time getting just what this 4-cocycle should assign to a 4-simplex in $K(\pi_2,2)$. I am primarily interested in understanding the map from the right to the left.

I have a guess at something which may be close, which is there is a canonical closed 2-form on $K(\pi_2,2)$ valued in $\pi_2$. Using the associated bilinear form of the given quadratic form, I can wedge this form with itself to obtain a closed 4-form valued in $U(1)$. I worry that instead of the ordinary square, I need to be doing some factoring, perhaps using the Pontryagin square instead.

Any help, especially with some intuition, would be much appreciated.

Comment: How does the tag 'characteristic-classes' apply? Perhaps the tag 'cohomology' would be more appropriate instead? Also, which article by Eilenberg and MacLane are you specifically referring to? They have several articles in the Annals of Mathematics.

Comment: I suppose you're right about the tags. I had this paper and its companion in mind. http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969702

Comment: There was a brief blog discussion at: http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/reference-hunt-i/

Comment: Thanks, Scott. That clarifies some of Whiteheads notation considerably.

Comment: If you have a quadratic form, you get a unique cohomology class in $H^4$, but if you want an explicit cocycle, you will have to make a noncanonical choice in the coboundary coset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To a quadratic form $q: \pi_2 \to U(1)$, we get a corresponding Pontryagin square operation $H^2(-; \pi_2) \to H^4(-; U(1))$, and such cohomology operations are given by elements of $H^4(K(\pi_2, 2); U(1))$. Unfortunately, I don't know if it's possible to get an explicit cochain-level description of the Pontryagin square operator just from the quadratic form. In Proposition 7.3 of my paper [*Extensions of groups by braided 2-groups*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0772.pdf), I write down a (group) cochain-level description of the Pontryagin square corresponding to an abelian 3-cocycle, but I don't know if there's a way in general to get an abelian 3-cocycle from a quadratic form. One good reference to look at is Baues's *Combinatorial Homotopy and 4-Dimensional Complexes*.

One intuitive way to think of the appearance of the Pontryagin square is that we are describing braided 2-groups with homotopy groups $\pi_2$ and $U(1)$, and the Pontryagin square operation $H^2(G; \pi_2) \to H^4(G; U(1))$ on a group $G$ is the obstruction to lifting an extension of $G$ by $\pi_2$ to an extension of $G$ by the entire braided 2-group (in the sense I describe in my paper).

EDIT: I should mention that you can avoid referring to the Pontryagin square directly. Per Baues, $H_4(K(\pi_2, 2); \mathbb{Z}) = \Gamma(\pi_2)$, the receptor of the universal quadratic map from $\pi_2$, so by universal coefficients, $H^4(K(\pi_2, 2); U(1)) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\Gamma(\pi_2), U(1))$, which is the same as quadratic forms on $\pi_2$ valued in $U(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Abelian 3-cocycles are indeed the same as quadratic forms. I don't know the isomorphism there either, though, so I think it might take me a while to get my answer out of your paper.

Comment: Actually I may have been mislead by the blog post Scott linked above, so don't take my word for that isomorphism.